# How to define dynamic getElementById in code?

Tags: javascript

We can use this code to get id:

```
document.getElementById("exampleid").value = 1;
```

and for example page code is

```
<input id="exampleid" value="" />
```

but we cannot use high code for this once, because `id` is different.

```
<input id="exampleid2" value="" />
```

And we should change our code to

```
document.getElementById("exampleid2").value = 1;
```

Now how can we define dynamic id?  Like:

```
document.getElementById('/^exampleid/').value = 1;
```

Note we do not want to change the code every time the html id changes.

Comment: To clarify, you want to change the value of every element that has an id that starts with `exampleid`. EG `exampleid1`, `exampleid2`?

Comment: if all the elements are of type input, why don't you just filter those to give you back the ones you want!

Comment: You can't use a `class` instead of `id` and call `getElementsByClassName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var eles = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=exampleid]");

for(var i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
    eles[i].value = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function replaceIdValue(idRegex, value) {
  document.querySelectorAll(`[id^=${idRegex}]`).forEach(element =>
    element.value = value
  )
}

replaceIdValue('exampleid', 1)
```

```html
<input id="exampleid1" value="" />
<input id="exampleid2" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When there's a need to select multiple objects you usually want to add a `class` to them:

```
<input type="text" id="exampleid1" class="exampleid" value="" />
<input type="text" id="exampleid2" class="exampleid" value="" />
<input type="text" id="exampleid3" class="exampleid" value="" />
```

Then you can select all of them by their common class:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('exampleid');
for ( var index in elements ) {
    var elem = elements[index];
    elem.value = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Var arofele;
for(var i=0;i<n;i++;)
{
var t="ele"+i;
arofele[i]=document.getElementById(t);
}
```

This might work i think but u have to pass n value and using getElementsByclass is efficient way if indeed u need to do with element id u can go with it